# How to connect to github using Java Program

Tags: java, github

Could someone help me how to connect to Github & how to upload a document using Java program ?

I want to connect to Github and once its connected I want to upload a document to github using Java program.

Many thanks,
Raju

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core

Comment: We need more details. If you want to connect with github you may need to use github api. Try to hit the follow url https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet you should get some data back which is JSON. Use a framework like servlet or spring mvc to make calls to github api. Please read documentation and provide more information such as are you developing a web app/console application/desktop app ?

Comment: @djam I am not developing any app..My requirement is just to upload a file to GitHub using Java, I tried to do using Github API but still couldnt able to authenticate..

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use one of the **Github** libraries. If you are interested in Java then you need to use [this one](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core).

First you need to authenticate using your **Github** account. Here is the sample from readme:

```
//Basic authentication
GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient();
client.setCredentials("user", "passw0rd");
//OAuth2 token authentication
GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient();
client.setOAuth2Token("SlAV32hkKG");
```

Then it depends on how you want to upload a document to **Github**. The simplest is to create a [Gist](https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/). To do it use the following code:

```
GistFile file = new GistFile();
file.setContent("System.out.println(\"Hello World\");");
Gist gist = new Gist();
gist.setDescription("Prints a string to standard out");
gist.setFiles(Collections.singletonMap("Hello.java", file));
GistService service = new GistService();
service.getClient().setCredentials("user", "passw0rd");
gist = service.createGist(gist); //returns the created gist
```

**Note** Gists are publicly available so if you want to make it private you need to do it explicitly

Comment: Hi Anatolli, I couldnt able to find GitHubClient class in Github API ..

Comment: Hi. Here it is https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/client/GitHubClient.java. Please, make sure you added library correctly. Do you use some build tool like Maven?

Comment: Ya it's in the org.eclipse.egit.github library,not in GitHub API-- I am using Gradle and now if i want to check whether i could able to authenticate to Github how to do that-- I wrote the GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient();
client.setCredentials("user", "passw0rd"); But how to verify that the authentcaton is success ? Do i need to write any assert statement here ? could u pls help in detail pls..

Comment: You need to wrap service.createGist(gist) call in try catch block. There are basically two exceptions you are interested in: IOException and RequestException. IOException means that there is some interaction error related to transfer. RequestException is defined in the library to indicate api interaction error. Check this https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/client/RequestException.java. Request exception has the status code inside. For authentication error it's usually 401