# How to access an external github repository to copy file from there (java)

Tags: java, github, gradle, yaml

Background information:
I have a small java application (using quarkus/gradle) that simply provides REST API from other services' yaml file. Currently, the yaml files are copied to this repository manually which needs to be automated.

Therefore, I need to access a github repository where the original yaml files exists and copy those yaml files from there into my own repository.

This is what I found out from my research here, but this didn't really help to solve my problem:
[How to connect to github using Java Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282945/how-to-connect-to-github-using-java-program)

Anyone idea how this is realizeable/ How the access to another repository can be enabled using github token?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to explain in much more detail what you want to do. Please read [ask].

Comment: thank you for the hint, I just edited my question, is it now better?

Comment: The library mentioned in the answer you linked to seemed like a good start. How far did you get and where are you stuck?

Comment: I couldn't find the gradle dependency for this githubrepository...